# Poner etiqueta title de imágenes como parrafo del mismo div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carrusel

Tengo un sencillo carrusel de imágenes generado por un plugin en Wordpress, ese carrusel pone las imagenes y pone la etiqueta `title` y la etiqueta `alt` que va muy bien ahí, pero ahora deseo ponerle un nombre debajo de cada imagen, que este nombre sea su correspondiente tiene de cada imagen.

Intente con este código:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#licencias .slick-slide .wpcp-slide-image').each(function() {
    var text = $(".slick-slide .wpcp-slide-image img").attr("title");
    $('.slick-slide .wpcp-slide-image').append("<p>" + text + "</p>");
  })
})
```

```css
#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .wpcp-single-item {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-prev,
#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-next,
#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-prev:hover,
#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-next:hover {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-prev i,
#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-next i {
  color: #aaa;
}

#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-prev i:hover,
#sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440.sp-wpcp-4440 .slick-next i:hover {
  color: #52b3d9;
}


/* .wpcp-carousel-section.wpcp-standard {
      display: none;
    }
*/

.wpcp-carousel-section.wpcp-standard.slick-initialized {
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fusion-text carrusel-escudos" id="licencias">
  <div class="wpcp-carousel-wrapper wpcp-wrapper-4440">
    <div id="sp-wp-carousel-free-id-4440" class="wpcp-carousel-section sp-wpcp-4440 nav-vertical-center wpcp-image-carousel wpcp-standard slick-initialized slick-slider" data-slick="{ &quot;accessibility&quot;:true, &quot;arrows&quot;:true, &quot;autoplay&quot;:true, &quot;autoplaySpeed&quot;:3000, &quot;dots&quot;:false, &quot;infinite&quot;:true, &quot;speed&quot;:600, &quot;pauseOnHover&quot;:true, &quot;slidesToShow&quot;:7, &quot;responsive&quot;:[ { &quot;breakpoint&quot;:1200, &quot;settings&quot;: { &quot;slidesToShow&quot;:7 } }, { &quot;breakpoint&quot;:980, &quot;settings&quot;:{ &quot;slidesToShow&quot;:3 } }, { &quot;breakpoint&quot;:736, &quot;settings&quot;: { &quot;slidesToShow&quot;:2 } }, {&quot;breakpoint&quot;:480, &quot;settings&quot;:{ &quot;slidesToShow&quot;:1, &quot;arrows&quot;: true, &quot;dots&quot;: false } } ], &quot;swipe&quot;: true, &quot;swipeToSlide&quot;: true, &quot;draggable&quot;: true }"
      dir="ltr">
      <div class="slick-prev slick-arrow" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
      <div class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track">
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-7" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/13.png" title="CF AMERICA" alt="CF AMERICA" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-6" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/16.png" title="ARGENTINA NATIONAL TEAM" alt="ARGENTINA NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-5" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/17.png" title="COLOMBIA NATIONAL TEAM" alt="COLOMBIA NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/19.png" title="FRENCH NATIONAL TEAM" alt="FRENCH NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/15.png" title="GERMANY NATIONAL TEAM" alt="GERMANY NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/18.png" title="MEXICO NATIONAL TEAM" alt="MEXICO NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/34.png" title="NETHERLANDS NATIONAL TEAM" alt="NETHERLANDS NATIONAL TEAM" width="82" height="96"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/mas-peque.png" title="FC BARCELONA" alt="FC BARCELONA" width="80" height="96"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2.png" title="REAL MADRID CF" alt="REAL MADRID CF" width="200" height="186"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/3.png" title="ARSENAL" alt="ARSENAL" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/4.png" title="LIVERPOOL FC" alt="LIVERPOOL FC" width="200" height="200"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/5.png" title="MANCHESTER CITY FC" alt="MANCHESTER CITY FC" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/6.png" title="CHELSEA" alt="CHELSEA" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="6" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/12.png" title="PARIS SAINT GERMAN" alt="PARIS SAINT GERMAN" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="7" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/14.png" title="SPAIN NATIONAL TEAM" alt="SPAIN NATIONAL TEAM" width="199" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="8" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 169px;" tabindex="-1">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/7.png" title="BENFICA" alt="BENFICA" width="191" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="9" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/8.png" title="FC PORTO" alt="FC PORTO" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="10" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/9.png" title="JUVENTUS FC" alt="JUVENTUS FC" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="11" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/10.png" title="INTER MILAN" alt="INTER MILAN" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="12" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/11.png" title="AC MILAN" alt="AC MILAN" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="13" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/21.png" title="SPORTING" alt="SPORTING" width="162" height="188"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="14" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/13.png" title="CF AMERICA" alt="CF AMERICA" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="15" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/16.png" title="ARGENTINA NATIONAL TEAM" alt="ARGENTINA NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="16" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/17.png" title="COLOMBIA NATIONAL TEAM" alt="COLOMBIA NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="17" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/19.png" title="FRENCH NATIONAL TEAM" alt="FRENCH NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="18" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/15.png" title="GERMANY NATIONAL TEAM" alt="GERMANY NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="19" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/18.png" title="MEXICO NATIONAL TEAM" alt="MEXICO NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="20" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/34.png" title="NETHERLANDS NATIONAL TEAM" alt="NETHERLANDS NATIONAL TEAM" width="82" height="96"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="21" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/mas-peque.png" title="FC BARCELONA" alt="FC BARCELONA" width="80" height="96"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="22" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2.png" title="REAL MADRID CF" alt="REAL MADRID CF" width="200" height="186"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="23" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/3.png" title="ARSENAL" alt="ARSENAL" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="24" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/4.png" title="LIVERPOOL FC" alt="LIVERPOOL FC" width="200" height="200"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="25" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/5.png" title="MANCHESTER CITY FC" alt="MANCHESTER CITY FC" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="26" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/6.png" title="CHELSEA" alt="CHELSEA" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="27" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/12.png" title="PARIS SAINT GERMAN" alt="PARIS SAINT GERMAN" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="28" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/14.png" title="SPAIN NATIONAL TEAM" alt="SPAIN NATIONAL TEAM" width="199" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="29" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/7.png" title="BENFICA" alt="BENFICA" width="191" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="30" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/8.png" title="FC PORTO" alt="FC PORTO" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="31" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/9.png" title="JUVENTUS FC" alt="JUVENTUS FC" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="32" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/10.png" title="INTER MILAN" alt="INTER MILAN" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="33" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/11.png" title="AC MILAN" alt="AC MILAN" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="34" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/21.png" title="SPORTING" alt="SPORTING" width="162" height="188"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="35" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/13.png" title="CF AMERICA" alt="CF AMERICA" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="36" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/16.png" title="ARGENTINA NATIONAL TEAM" alt="ARGENTINA NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="37" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/17.png" title="COLOMBIA NATIONAL TEAM" alt="COLOMBIA NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="38" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/19.png" title="FRENCH NATIONAL TEAM" alt="FRENCH NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="39" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/15.png" title="GERMANY NATIONAL TEAM" alt="GERMANY NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="40" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/18.png" title="MEXICO NATIONAL TEAM" alt="MEXICO NATIONAL TEAM" width="200" height="203"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="41" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 169px;">
            <div>
              <div class="wpcp-single-item" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="wpcp-slide-image"><img src="https://www.minigols.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/34.png" title="NETHERLANDS NATIONAL TEAM" alt="NETHERLANDS NATIONAL TEAM" width="82" height="96"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-next slick-arrow" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/acsistemas/hqfxkdgo/2/

Pero no me resulto, me esta copiando el title de la primera imagen y lo pone al resto, pero lo pone muchas veces.

Por favor, ¿como hago para que el nombre solo se vea una sola vez y se vea cada imagen su correspondiente `title`?

Gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema era que no estabas obteniendo cada valor dentro del *foreach*, y eso generaba un ciclo. La forma de solucionarlo es obtener cada valor como un objeto de *jQuery* para poder trabajar con él e imprimir el nombre en cada elemento correspondiente.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //Aquí obtenemos los elementos.
  $('#licencias .slick-slide .wpcp-slide-image').each(function(index, value) {
    //Se transforma en un objeto de jQuery para poder trabajarlo
    var text = $(value).children('img').attr('title');
    $(value).append("<p>" + text + "</p>");
  })
})
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por todo, la verdad me resulto con tu ayuda. un abrazo